# How do I find the values of $a$ and $b$ in $\sin(ax-b)$ in the following example?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Given that for the translated curve $\sin(ax-b)$ the following points have been transformed: 
$$0\mapsto\frac{\pi}{10},\, \pi\mapsto \frac{3\pi}{5},\, 2\pi\mapsto \frac{11\pi}{10}$$
What are the values of a and b?

My brain is tangled up pretty hard on this one. I interpret the transformations as 'a stretch factor of $\dfrac{1}{a} $is applied to all $x$ coordinates, then a translation factor of $+b$ is applied to all $x$ coordinates'.

By this logic, I can do the following:
$\left(\dfrac{0}{a}\right)+b = \dfrac{\pi}{10}$, implying that $b=\dfrac{\pi}{10}$ (Using the transformed zero coordinate)
$\dfrac{\pi}{a}+b=\dfrac{3\pi}{5}$, implying that $a=2$.

However, this isn't the case. My teacher states that I should go about saying that $f(x)=\sin(x)$, therefore $f(ax)=\sin(ax)=g(x)$. Then it follows that $g(x-(\frac{b}{a}))=\sin[a(x-(\frac{b}{a}))]$.

I have a huge problem with this. Why is it incorrect to say that 
$f(ax-b)$ gives the desired graph? If I wanted to transform a sine graph, why is it implausible to stretch the graph by a factor $\dfrac{1}{a}$ then translate it to the right by amount $+b$? It seems perfectly logical.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is :

$(1)$ Stretch the graph by $ \dfrac 1a$ That is $$x \to ax$$

$(2)$ **Then** shift towards right by $+b$ That is

$$ax \to a(x-b)$$

Thus you get the transformation $$f(x)\to f(ax-ab)$$

I hope you understand what you are doing wrong.

---

The correct way to apply the transformation $$f(x) \to f(ax+b)$$ is to do the step $(2)$ and *then* $(1)$.

Comment: If we let f(x)=x, then f(ax)=ax=g(x),. Therefore, g(x-b)=ax-ab, which is the same problem that I've been having. Having worked on it, I believe that there is a better way to understand it sir. The most important thing to notice is that whenever you transform a function, you have to change the function notation, and this will allow you to make sure that you're still actually transforming your desired function.

Answer (score 0):

> I interpret the transformations as 'a stretch factor of $\dfrac{1}{a} $is applied to all $x$ coordinates, then a translation factor of $+b$ is applied to all $x$ coordinates'.

This order isn't correct.  In general, the order is:

1. **H**orizontal translations
2. **S**tretching/shrinking (both horizontally and vertically)
3. **R**eflecting over the $x$-axis and/or $y$-axis.
4. **V**ertical translations

This corresponds to the so-called HSRV method of analyzing transformations of graphs.  There are other methods, but when you have $f(ax-b)$ in general, the idea is to write that as $f(a(x-\frac ba))$ so that you have a horizontal shift of $\frac ba$ and a horizontal stretch/shrink factor of $a$.

> Why is it incorrect to say that 
>   $f(ax-b)$ gives the desired graph? If I wanted to transform a sine graph, why is it implausible to stretch the graph by a factor $\dfrac{1}{a}$ then translate it to the right by amount $+b$?

The horizontal stretch/shrink also affects the horizontal shift.  This is why the shift must be done first.  If you insist on doing the stretch/shrink first, **then you also need to stretch/shrink the amount by which you shift.**  For example, "shrinking" the point $(2,3)$ by a factor of $2$ to the point $(1,3)$ and then shifting it to the right $8$ units to $(9,3)$ is **not** the same as shifting $(2,3)$ to the right by $8$ units to $(10,3)$ and then "shrinking" by a factor of $2$ to $(5,3)$.  This second method, where we obtained $(5,3)$, is the correct way because we accounted for the fact that our shrink affects the horizontal shift.  In the first method we didn't account for the fact that the shrink affects the horizontal shift.  To fix the first method we'd have to shift $(1,3)$ to the right by $4 (=8/2)$ units because of the shrinking by a factor of $2$.

Let's look more closely at a specific example with $f(x) = \sin x$, $a = 2$, and $b = \pi/2$.  For simplicity we'll restrict our attention to one single period.  Here's the graph of $y = f(x)$ on $[0,2\pi]$.  Note the labeled point $\left(\dfrac\pi2, 1\right)$.  (All graphs below were made with [desmos.com](https://www.desmos.com/).)

[image]

Here's the graph of $f(x)$ after it has been stretched by a factor of $1/a = 1/2$ (so technically, shrunk/compressed by a factor of $2$).  Note the labeled point $\left(\dfrac\pi4, 1\right)$, and note that the length of one period has been cut in half.

[image]

Now here's the preceding graph shifted to the right by $b = \pi/2$ units.  This is the graph that you expect is $y = \sin\left(2x-\dfrac\pi2\right)$, but in fact it is $y = \sin\left(2\left(x - \dfrac\pi2\right)\right)$.  Note that our labeled point has been shifted to the right by $b$ units.

[image]

The graph of $y = f\left(2x-\dfrac\pi2\right)$ actually is this:

[image]

Note that this graph is the graph of $y = f(2x)$ shifted to the right by $\pi/4$ units (which is $b/a$, not $b$), and this is expected since $f\left(2x-\dfrac\pi2\right) = f\left(2\left(x - \dfrac\pi4\right)\right)$.

It's a little crowded, but here are all four graphs together in case it helps.  Note especially how the purple graph (the one you thought should be $y = \sin\left(2x-\dfrac\pi2\right)$) is different from the green graph (the one that actually is $y = \sin\left(2x - \dfrac\pi2\right)$).

[image]

---

There's nothing unique about the sine function that makes this behavior true here and not true elsewhere.  It's true in general that the graph of $y = f(ax-b)$ is **not** the graph of $y = f(x)$ that's been stretched/shrunk by a factor of $1/a$ and *then* shifted by $b$ units.  It's the graph of $y = f(x)$ that's been shifted by $b/a$ and *then* stretched/shrunk by a factor of $1/a$.  And as mentioned earlier in the post, the reason is that the horizontal stretch/shrink also affects the horizontal shift.

---

All that aside, you're actually overthinking the specific problem you were originally given.  I'd approach it like this:

The old coordinate $x=0$ gets transformed to the new coordinate $ax - b = \pi/10$.  In other words, when $x = 0$ then $ax - b = \pi/10$.  So $a \cdot 0 - b = \pi/10$, giving us $b = -\pi/10$.

The old coordinate $x=\pi$ gets transformed to the new coordinate $ax + \pi/10 = 3\pi/5$.  In other words, when $x = \pi$ then $ax +\pi/10 = 3\pi/5$.  So $a \cdot \pi +\pi/10 = 3\pi/5$, giving us $a = 1/2$.

Technically we're done, but since we have another transformed coordinate we might as well use it to verify our results.

The old coordinate $x = 2\pi$ gets transformed to the new coordinate $\dfrac12 x + \dfrac\pi{10} = \dfrac{11\pi}{10}$.  Verify by plugging in $x = 2\pi$: $$\dfrac12 \cdot 2\pi + \dfrac\pi{10} = \dfrac{11\pi}{10}$$  This equation is true, thus we confirmed that $a = 1/2$ and $b = -\pi/10$ are correct.